# Assertions (contracts) and unit testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Say I have a method

```
public void PrintStuff(string stuff, Color color, PageDimensions dimensions)
{
     Assert.IsNotNull("color");
     Assert.IsNotNull(dimensions);
     Assert.IsTrue(dimensions.width < 20.0);
}
```

and I have another method `AnotherMethod()` which is calling `PrintStuff()`. Let's assume `PrintStuff()` is defined in some interfaces that `AnotherMethod()` is using. The question is: when writing a unit test for `AnotherMethod()` how can I **automate** testing that `AnotherMethod()` does not pass any values into `PrintStuff()` that violate its assertions?

Something like:

```
printer.Expect(x => x.PrintStuff(null, null, null)).CheckAssertions();
```

The solution should support a change in assertions automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `PrintStuff` is in an interface but your assertions are in a concrete class, who's to say the same assertions apply to all implementations? It sounds like what you really want is to give contracts to the *interface* rather than the concrete class. Obviously you can't do that in "normal" C# code...

Now, I'd suggest using [Code Contracts](http://research.microsoft.com/contracts) which support contract inheritance, including interfaces. If you're using Visual Studio Premium or Ultimate editions, you can have *compile-time* static checking that you don't violate the assertions. Otherwise, you're back to mocking I believe. Now if you use mocking, I don't think the contracts will automatically be picked up, because they're usually applied using binary rewriting... but I'd expect the tooling in this area to improve reasonably soon. Of course, mocking usually involves specifying the inputs you expect anyway, so you should be able to make sure they're valid when you write your tests anyway.

You may also want to look at [Pex](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/) which explores your code and tries to break it for you.

Comment: That's awesome. I guess I can just write a helper method to check the contracts with that thing.